# How can I get the genres and the number of songs of each genres in one query in Android?

Tags: android, audio, cursor, mediastore

I get the genres:

```
public static CursorLoader getGenres(Context context) {
    Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Genres.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    String[] columns = { MediaStore.Audio.Genres._ID,
            MediaStore.Audio.Genres.NAME };
    String orderBy = MediaStore.Audio.Genres.NAME;

    return new CursorLoader(context, uri, columns, null, null, orderBy);
}
```

But I need the number of songs of each genre. I can do this for each genre:

```
private int getNumberSongsOfGenre(long genreID) {
    Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Genres.Members.getContentUri(VOLUMENAME,
            genreID);
    Cursor c = resolver.query(uri, null, null, null, null);

    if (c == null || c.getCount() == 0)
        return -1;

    int num = c.getCount();
    c.close();

    return num;
}
```

...but I need do it in the same query and return a CursorLoader. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I am also looking for same thing but still not get any proper solution. But if you only concern with the number of songs to display then you can do something like my answer below.

```
@Override
    public void bindView(View v, Context context, Cursor c) {
        int index;
        long genreId;
        Uri uri;
        ViewHolder holder  =   (ViewHolder)    v.getTag();

         holder.titleName.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Genres.NAME)));
         //===========================

         index = c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Genres.NAME);            
         //Log.i("Tag-Genre name", c.getString(index));

         index = c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Genres._ID);             
         //genreId=Long.parseLong(c.getString(index));
         genreId  = c.getLong(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Genres._ID));
         uri = MediaStore.Audio.Genres.Members.getContentUri("external", genreId);
         String[] proj2={MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME};
         Cursor tempcursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, proj2, null,null,null);
         //tempcursor.moveToFirst();
         //Log.i("Tag-Number of songs for this genre", tempcursor.getCount()+"");
         holder.artistName.setText(""+tempcursor.getCount()+" Songs");

    }
```

Hope you got the answer if you only concern with display number of Songs in it.

Comment: anything u have found regarding this ?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
ArrayList<GenreInfo> infos = new ArrayList<>();
    Cursor c = getAllGenre(search);
    if (c!=null) {
        c.moveToFirst();
        while (!c.isAfterLast()) {
            GenreInfo genreInfo = new GenreInfo();
            genreInfo.setID(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Genres._ID)));
            genreInfo.setName(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Genres.NAME)));
            Cursor count = ourContext.getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Audio.Genres.Members.
                    getContentUri("external", Long.parseLong(genreInfo.getID())), null, null, null, null);
            genreInfo.setNumOfSongs(count.getCount());
            infos.add(genreInfo);
            count.close();
            c.moveToNext();
        }
    }
    if (c!=null) c.close();
    return infos;
```